# Не работает перебор участников в discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Нужно чтобы бот перебрал всех участников на сервере. При переборе выводится только сам бот и его тег.

Вот мой код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!member'):
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                print(member)
```

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html?highlight=intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При инициализации бота, необходимо выдать ему `намерения`

**Если вы используете в качестве бота `discord.Client()`**:

```
bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

**Если вы используете в качестве бота `discord.ext.commands.Bot()`**:

```
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!member'):
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                await ctx.send(member.mention)
```

Comment: В вашем код вы добавили `await ctx.send(member.mention)` как это поможет в проблеме перебора участников?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]